# Azure dynamic group based licenses

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We are now allocating group based licenses in Azure, but there are a lot of people who were onboarded a while ago and have not accepted the invitation yet, therefore we needed to remove users from dynamic groups for who have not accepted the invitation, so that we may reduce license consumption.

But "Invitation acceptance state" is not available in dynamic group rules; is there any way to do this?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/use-dynamic-groups

Thanks
Dev

Comment: Can you give more context? Is Azure AD or? :thinking:

Comment: @Drumor Its Azure AD and P2 Linceses

Comment: @DevReddy Could you include what dynamic membership rules you used for creating dynamic groups?

Comment: (user.mail -match "@xyz.com$") and (user.accountEnabled -eq true)  - This will add users with xyz.com to dynamic group and it will remove users who got disabled once they left the organisation, so that we can reuse those licenses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To **remove** members from dynamic group, you need to modify dynamic membership rule.
>
> As "Invitation state" property is not available in dynamic group rules, you can make use of **PowerShell** script to achieve your requirement as an alternative way.

I have few users having "Invitation state" as **`PendingAcceptance`** as below:

[image]

When I created dynamic group with **membership rule** as *(user.mail -match "@xyz.com") and (user.accountEnabled -eq true)*, I got members in group like this:

[image]

Now, I ran below PowerShell script that filters users with "Invitation state" as **`PendingAcceptance`** and excludes them in membership rule:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Directory.ReadWrite.All"
$groupId = "dynamicgroupId"
$users = Get-MgUser -Filter "externalUserState eq 'PendingAcceptance'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Id | ConvertTo-Json
$domain = "@xyz.com"
$rule = "(user.mail -match ""$domain"") and (user.accountEnabled -eq true) and -not (user.objectId -in $users)"
$rule
Update-MgGroup -GroupId $groupId -MembershipRule $rule
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, dynamic membership rule updated successfully as below:

[image]

This automatically removed users with **`PendingAcceptance`** state from dynamic group like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, it makes sence but the problem is its adding object id and it will work for only existing users, what if the new users comes and they are not accepting the invitation, then they will be added to the group and not get removed

Comment: It's just an alternative as "Invitation state" property is not available in dynamic group rules. You need to run this PowerShell script frequently that modifies the dynamic  membership rule often by adding object IDs of new users too with `PendingAcceptance` state to exclude from group.